# ArrayList containing different objects of the same superclass - how to access method of a subclass

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, subclass, superclass

*Hi I'm wondering if there is a simple solution to my problem,*

I have an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList <Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>(); 

/* I add some objects from subclasses of Animal */

animalList.add(new Reptile());
animalList.add(new Bird());
animalList.add(new Amphibian());
```

They all implement a method `move()` - The `Bird` flies when `move()` is called. 
I know I can access common methods and properties of the super class by using this

```
public void feed(Integer animalIndex) {
    Animal aAnimal = (Animal) this.animalList.get(animalIndex);
    aAnimal.eat();
}
```

That's fine - but now I would like to access the `move()` method the subclass `Bird` has.
I could do this by casting the `Animal` as a `Bird`:

```
Bird aBird = (Bird) this.animalList.get(animalIndex);
aBird.move();
```

In my situation I don't want to do this, as it will mean I have 3 different sets of the above code one for each subtype of `Animal`.

It seems a bit redundant, is there a better way?

Comment: Why wouldn't Animal have a `move()` method that you override in the subclasses?

Comment: ... Call move? If it's not calling the subclass implementation there's something you're not telling us.

Comment: @user2278797 Just so you know: I edited your question for better formatting and changed the classes' names (as they were inconsistent among your code): I removed the `s`-es from the their names in the lines they were added to `animalList`. They were: `animalList.add(new Reptiles()); animalList.add(new Birds()); animalList.add(new Amphibians());` And now are: `animalList.add(new Reptile()); animalList.add(new Bird()); animalList.add(new Amphibian());`. If you used them in any code of yours, make sure you change them accordingly or re-edit your question's code.

Comment: I'm massively puzzled over why this is so up-voted, because the question is nonsense and suggests misunderstanding of polymorphism concepts. It seems that the OP believes that the `(Animal)` cast in the first block of code will cause the superclass' `move()` implementation to be called. It will not, because the overridden `move()` of the subclass that the object actually is will be called. In other words, that `(Animal)` class is totally redundant, and the Java language already provides the exact functionality being asked for without changing anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There really isn't a nice way to do this from the superclass, since the behavior of each subclass will be different.

To ensure that you're actually calling the appropriate `move` method, change `Animal` from a superclass to an interface.  Then when you call the `move` method, you'll be able to ensure that you're calling the appropriate move method for the object you want.

If you're looking to preserve common fields, then you can define an abstract class `AnimalBase`, and require all animals to build off of that, but each implementation will need to implement the `Animal` interface.

Example:

```
public abstract class AnimalBase {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private boolean gender;

    // getters and setters for the above are good to have here
}

public interface Animal {
    public void move();
    public void eat();
    public void sleep();
}

// The below won't compile because the contract for the interface changed.
// You'll have to implement eat and sleep for each object.

public class Reptiles extends AnimalBase implements Animal {
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("Slither!");
    }
}

public class Birds extends AnimalBase implements Animal {
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("Flap flap!");
    }
}

public class Amphibians extends AnimalBase implements Animal {
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("Some sort of moving sound...");
    }
}

// in some method, you'll be calling the below

List<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<>();

animalList.add(new Reptiles());
animalList.add(new Amphibians());
animalList.add(new Birds());

// call your method without fear of it being generic

for(Animal a : animalList) {
    a.move();
}
```

Comment: Okay but what about all the common methods and behaviors that are shared between the subclasses. Wouldit not be redundant to declare the same methods and properties that do and describe the same things in each separate subclass? For example I have some common properties name, gender, color etc and then some methods like eat and sleep. Thanks for your quick replies by the way.

Comment: At that point, you *could* have an abstract object called `AnimalBase`, which provides the fields you need.  You then would want to extend from that, and implement the `Animal` interface.

Comment: Thanks Makoto, Can I ask if there is a more correct way of solving this problem ? e.g. is it better to use a base abstract class and implement the other methods or would it be better to leave certain methods blank and override them for each subclass? Cheers

Comment: Using an interface, which at least ensures that the method is present at compile time, would be the best way to do it.  That's the method I've applied here.  The abstract class was to get around creating the same field in each subclass over and over again.

Comment: thanks Makoto. I have had a go at it and it works so thanks. What If I wanted to access specific properties of the Reptile class ? I didn't want to have to do this but perhaps I need to add an if statement for certain methods to find out what type of animal a is exactly. e.g. if ( a instanceof bird) then cast to a bird object and access maxFlightDistance property, if (a instanceof reptile) cast to reptile and access reptile property.This would work but going back t my original problem it seems redundant to do this every time I need to work out what type of animal I am using.What do u think?

Comment: This answer puzzles me just as the original question does. I just don't understand why the OP would need to implement an interface like this at all. As per my comment below the question (and in agreement with the answer by Lokesh also), surely the OP's aim is already achieved by simple polymorphism, specifically by each subclass implementing a superclass `move()` method?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to do any casting. The overridden method should get called [simple polymorphism]

```
Animal aAnimal==  this.animalList.get(animalIndex);
aAnimal.move();
```

Above code should call bird method if object is of bird, isn't it?

And casting is not a solution , how will you decide which object to cast? You will have to use instanceOf.

Comment: Thanks , could be a possible solution. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by And casting is not a solution , how will you decide which object to cast? You will have to use instanceOf" , The user would click on an object i.e an animal and that would pass the index number of where for where it is placed in the arrayList.. Cheers

Comment: So you doing like this: animalList.add(new Reptile());
animalList.add(new Bird());
animalList.add(new Amphibian()); Now while retrieving objects either you have to keep track of which object is at which location to do proper casting or you need instanceof operator to check that otherwise you may end up casting Amphibian to Bird. You got my point?

Comment: Ok I think so - if I did this instead

Comment: Ok I think so - if I did this instead: public void createAnimal(){ Bird b = new Bird();   this.animalList.add(b);} - Yea, still not sure if I can keep track of them that way either.

Comment: You can't there is no way. You are reaching a situation which existed before generics where we had to keep track of types using instanceof.

Answer (score 0):

In your case,the following could work,but time complexity is O(n):

```
public void moveBird(){
    for(Animal aminal:animalList){
        if(animal instanceof Bird){
            aninmal.move();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume each Animal has a move() method.

Answer (score -1):

```
Bird getMyBird(Integer aniInteger) {
        Bird b = new Bird();
        //Do somthig with bird object...

        return b;
        //get your modifeid bird object
    }

    Bird myBird = animalList.get(animalIndex);

    myBird.move();
```

Comment: What are you even *doing* with this?  All I wanted to do was call `move` on any type of `Animal`.  Why are you so focused on `Bird`?

Comment: Yea there is no focus on bird - was just using it as an example.