# How to load All Arraylist from the model function?

Tags: java, json, android, gson

I'm using lib [FlexibleAdapter](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter/) to load JSON API in android studio like this.

```
public void createHolderSectionsDatabase(int size, int headers) {
    databaseType = DatabaseType.MODEL_HOLDERS;
    HeaderHolder header = null;
    mItems.clear();
    int lastHeaderId = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        header = i % Math.round(size / headers) == 0 ? newHeaderHolder(++lastHeaderId) : header;
        mItems.add(newItemHolder(i + 1, header));
    }
}

private HeaderHolder newHeaderHolder(int i) {
    HeaderModel model = new HeaderModel("H" + i);
    model.setTitle("Header " + i);
    return new HeaderHolder(model);
}

private ItemHolder newItemHolder(int i, HeaderHolder header) {
    ItemModel model = new ItemModel("I" + i);
    model.setTitle("Holder Item " + i);
    model.setSubtitle("Subtitle " + i);
    return new ItemHolder(model, header);
}
```

Above code only loads the data from looping model item.

I could apply with JSON API such as:

How to change code like:

```
/*      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            header = i % Math.round(size / headers) == 0 ? newHeaderHolder(++lastHeaderId) : header;
            mItems.add(newItemHolder(i + 1, header));
        }*/
```

Like this:

```
    listArrayFromJSON = getArrayJSON(); //get JSON with GSON request
    mItems.addAll(ListArrayFromJSON,header); //not add`
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your json string structure but, you can update question or inspire from below

```
public class DataHolder{
     private ArrayList<ItemHolder> items; //json object name
     private ArrayList<HeaderHolder> headers; //json object name

     public Arraylist<ItemHolder> getItems(){
        return items;
     }

     public Arraylist<HeaderHolder> getHeaders(){
        return items;
     }
}

DataHolder holder = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, DataHolder.class);
mItems.addAll(holder.getItems());
mHeaders.addAll(holder.getHeaders());
```

Comment: How do I combine the two models `HeaderModel` and `ItemModel` into One ArrayList. So when not like `mItems.addAll(ListArrayFromJSON,header); //not` but like this : `mItems.addAll(ListArrayHeaderAndItemFromJSON);`

Comment: I update the answer but Do you want to do this `ArrayList<HeaderItemHolder> headersAndItems`?

Comment: Do you want to add different classes to one arraylist?

Comment: Yes, i want to do like this `ArrayList<HeaderItemHolder> headersAndItems`

Comment: this is a java subject you need to create a super class and extend it from sub classes. Then you can add them to a single array. You need to check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995540/arraylist-containing-different-objects-of-the-same-superclass-how-to-access-me and learn java inheritance but this is not an android question